# Batch: Finding Interstitial String and Concatenating HTML Tag On Same Line

Tags: string, powershell, batch-file

I have hundreds of .htm files. They're all different, but they all share a similar link near the end:

```
<a href="123-04.htm">Please Consult 345.</a>
```

The "123-04" filename and the "345" may be different across all the .htm files in the set, but the "Please Consult" is always the same.

So I want to search all the .htm files for the string "Please Consult" and then add `<a name="Tag"></a>` onto the beginning of the line where that occurs in each file to produce the following:

```
<a name="Tag"></a><a href="123-04.htm">Please Consult 345.</a>
```

I've tried a few things. First was using findstr, which can find the string, but is never able to report the line number accurately. It always reports line 1. From reading, I believe this is due to the .htm files being UNIX. I have no idea what that means, but have read that it interferes with findstr. Again, novice, my apologies.

I wrote a sample script based on solutions I found on this site that steps through the file using `for /f` and I think I'm onto something, but I cannot figure out how to have it "look" for the "Please Consult" string, since it's in the middle of the line. And there are no delimiters or anything I can use to specify tokens, right? The script copies all the lines to a new file, and if it finds a particular string while it's stepping, it will insert another string below that line into a new text file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f %%x in (sample.txt) do (
    set line=%%x
    echo %%x>>newfile.txt
    call :ADD
)

:ADD
if /I "!line!"=="1" (
echo inserttext>>newfile.txt
)
```

The sample.txt just contains 10 lines, each having its own number (1 to 10). This works, of course, so I think I've started down the path with a proof of concept, but it's not quite what I need. I know IF statements don't do wildcards, so I'm not sure that's even the right way to go about this, since the string I need to search is in the middle of the line, rather than at the beginning like in the sample.txt.

Needless to say I'm stuck. I've put this under batch, but I'm open to using powershell or anything intrinsically available on Windows. This is for work, so it wouldn't be straightforward for me to get something special. If this were MATLAB or FORTRAN or something I've used extensively before, I'm sure I could figure it out, but I'm just not knowledgeable enough with the tools available. I hope I've provided a detailed question and shown due diligence in my attempts to find an already-existing answer.

Comment: `<a name="Tag"></a>` is a fixed string or "Tag" should be `123-04.htm` ?

Comment: You  actually described what you've tried after using the sentence "I've tried a few things." +1 just for that.

Comment: Let me recommend not to use batch scripting for HTML manipulation; use a language that is capable of handling HTML natively; Windows `cmd`/batch treat HTML as normal text files and may therefore disrupt the data structure...

Comment: @pandemic - yes it's a fixed string. It should say "Tag" every time it's appended to the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular Expressions to the rescue!

```
$input = Get-Content InputFile.txt
$input -replace '(<a.*?>.*?Please Consult.*?<\/a>)','<a name="Tag"></a>$1' | Out-File OutputFile.txt
```

Basic ideas:

The regular expression `'(<a.*?>.*?Please Consult.*?<\/a>)'` matches all `<a>` and `</a>` tags that contain the words "Please Consult"

The Regular expression `.*?` is essentially match any text lazy (i.e. once you hit the bracket, stop). And finally the `()` brackets create a "match group" which we will use in the replacement.

The next part: `'<a name="Tag"></a>$1'` is the replacement text.

We want to replace with `<a name="Tag"></a>` and then followed by `$1` which is the contents of the Match Group. (i.e. what was there).

With a bit more PowerShell you can add loops to iterate through files and automate the replacements if desired.

Comment: That "-replace" line was what saved me. Was able to piece it together with some other find-replace-loop code I found elsewhere. Works perfectly. Thank you so much.